# confused about a "that clause"

Tags: meaning

Venus flytrap grows well in the sunny weather ***that the Carolinas enjoy most of the year***.

I understand Venus flytrap grows well in the sunny weather, but I am a little bit confused about the whole sentence. Does it mean sunny weather is most of the year in Carolinas, and the plant grows well in the sunny weather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence seems to be intended to say the following.

- It is sunny most of the year in the Carolinas.
- The people in the Carolinas enjoy it.
- The Venus flytrap grows well in this kind of weather.

The sentence is not particularly well constructed. You have to think about too much to understand what should be a simple statement. For example:

- Maybe the Carolinas should not be described as enjoying something, since it's a geographic location.
- You need to stop and worry about whether this sunny weather is present most of the year and enjoyed whenever it is there, or whether it is present all of the year but only enjoyed part of the year.

It might be better rewritten as two sentences.

> The Venus flytrap grows well in sunny temperate weather. The Carolinas
> have such weather most of the year.